cumulative distribution function of Z=min{X,Y}
Let $X, Y$ be two random variables with joint distribution function $F(x,y)=P(X≤x,Y≤y)$ and marginal distribution functions $F_X (x)$  and $F_Y (y)$. If $Z$ is the random variable $Z$=min⁡{X,Y}, then its cumulative distribution function $F_Z (t)$ is:
The answer is: $$ 
F_X (t)+F_Y (t)-F(t,t)  
$$
But I’ve not been able to reach this answer, so any guidance would be appreciated.

Maybe this will help you to start: $Z > t$ iff $X > t$ and $Y > t$. Can you express what this means for the probabilities in terms of cumulative distribution functions?

Tbh I also don't see how the answer you are providing is correct.

yeah i'm sorry it has to be +F_Y(t) not minus.

As points out in the comment, the event $\{Z > t\}$ can be expressed as:
$$
    \{Z > t\} = \{X > t\} \cap \{Y > t\}
$$
or,
$$
    \{Z \le t\} = \{X \le t\} \cup \{Y \le t\}
$$
Remind that for any two events $A$ and $B$, we have the following identity:
$$
    \mathbb{P}(A \cup B) = \mathbb{P}(A) + \mathbb{P}(B) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)
$$
Apply this identity with $A = \{X \le t\}, B = \{Y \le t\}$, we get:
$$
   \mathbb{P}(Z \le t) = \mathbb{P}(X \le t) + \mathbb{P}(Y \le t) - \mathbb{P}(X \le t, Y \le t) = F_X(t) + F_Y(t) - F(t, t)
$$

But when you say {Z≤t}={X≤t}∪{Y≤t}, what guarantees here that Z=min{X,Y}?

@waw11 I don't understand your question. We set $Z = \min{X, Y}$ correct ?

I'm sorry. I get it now. Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it
